MeshPhysicalMaterial properties is not applying
I am trying to create a glass like triangle for my project in 3js, but it is not working.
let vertices = new Float32Array([
  -1.0, -1.0, 1.0,    
   1.0, -1.0, 1.0,    
   1.0, 1.0, 1.0,    
]);
const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

geometry.setAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(vertices, 3));

const material = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial()

material.side = THREE.DoubleSide

material.metalness= 0;

material.roughness = 0;

material.transmission = 1;

material.ior = 1.54;

material.thickness = 5;

const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

scene.add(mesh)

I have just started to learn threejs, so any kind of help will be very much appriciated.

Try make more detailed geometry.
To compare check your geometry and torus (for example) with the same parameters.
And try this triangle:
const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
    
const vertices = new Float32Array([
                -1.0, -1.0, 0.0,
                 1.0, -1.0, 0.0,
                 0.0,  1.0, 0.0,
                 0.0, -0.5, 0.0,
                 0.5,  0.0, 0.0,
                -0.5,  0.0, 0.0
            ]);
const indices = new Uint16Array([
                0, 3, 5, 
                3, 1, 4, 
                4, 2, 5, 
                3, 4, 5  
            ]);
            geometry.setAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(vertices, 3));
            geometry.setIndex(new THREE.BufferAttribute(indices, 1));
            geometry.computeVertexNormals();

UPDATE
Torus + Triangles (Glossy material)
https://codepen.io/Lucas_Mas/pen/ExzmGwz

I want to make a crown like shape , where each side of the octagon will align with the base of eight triangles and the triangle will be vertical. I have used a torus as a base, and the "GlassLike" effect is working well on the torus but not on the triangles.
@Łukasz

@Proma I made update, in my opinion looks like glass…
